# Artifacts are not deployed with SSH Upload in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

So I have one job that produces artifacts, and another job with dependency on those artifacts from first job. I tried to use SSH Upload, however I inserted into field "Paths to sources" *.deb => /tmp
In order to download Debian packages from previous job to tmp, but it does not download anything

Logs from my job to deploy:

```
[21:54:49]  Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[21:54:54]  The build is removed from the queue to be prepared for the start
[21:54:54]  Starting the build on the agent "agent3"
[21:54:55]  Updating tools for build
[21:54:55]  Clearing temporary directory: /opt/buildagent/temp/buildTmp
[21:54:55]  Publishing internal artifacts
[21:54:55]  Full checkout enforced. Reason: [Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist]
[21:54:55]  Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[21:54:55]  Checkout directory: /opt/buildagent/work/245575fe8c01221b
[21:54:55]  Resolving artifact dependencies
[21:54:55]  [Resolving artifact dependencies] Destination directory [/tmp] cleaned
[21:54:55]  [Resolving artifact dependencies] Downloading files from <Xenoss.test / Build job of deb/rpm packages, build #0.0.2 [id 15836]> for pattern [*.deb => /tmp
*.rpm => /tmp]
[21:54:55]  [Resolving artifact dependencies] 2 files retrieved
[21:54:55]  Step 1/1: Upload deb/rpm package to destination server (SSH Upload) (1s)
[21:54:55]  [Step 1/1] Permanently added '139.59.178.103' (EDDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[21:54:56]  [Step 1/1] Starting upload via SCP to host [139.59.178.103:22]
[21:54:56]  [Step 1/1] Uploaded [0] files for [] pattern
[21:54:56]  Publishing internal artifacts
[21:54:56]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[21:54:56]  [Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisherImpl]
[21:54:56]  Build finished
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to fix your artifact dependency rule. In your setup:

1. TeamCity downloads artifacts to /tmp directory
2. TeamCity tries to upload *.deb from directory folder which is not equal to /tmp

So correct artfact dependency rule should look like this:

```
*.deb => .
```